# Unexpected memory usage after SSL on Apache

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, memory

We recently converted our web site to `https`.  After certificate installation and testing we created a 301 redirect in .htaccess.  Things went fine for a few days with little apparent performance impact.

Day 3 or 4 we ran into `OOM` issues.  Over the next few days we would see the same pattern repeated.  At about 9:15 AM (when our server starts to see increased load) our memory usage would creep up and often cause the server to kill memcached or mysql.  It's hard to understand because we'd see much much greater usage (per google analytics) later in the day with no problems at all.

```
Server Version: Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 PHP/5.5.38
Server MPM: prefork
Start servers: 10
Min spare servers: 5
server limit: 256
max request workers: 256
max connections per child: 2500*
keep alive: on
keep alive timeout: 1
```

I lowered max connections because we noticed that the mem usage per child seemed to increase significantly during the problem period. Per `htop` RES for each child is usually 25000k.  During stress it is over 50000k.  So I had a thought that I wanted to increase the frequency new child processes being spawned.  Unclear if this made any difference.

We've checked all `cron` jobs to ensure that nothing special is scheduled at the stress period.

Does adding `ssl` create significantly more mem usage for `apache`? Why only at this particular time - not even anywhere near our busiest time (although it might be the time that the usage grows the most).

Update.  We removed the 301 redirect to try to definitively determine if this was the cause.  Sure enough the server handled the 9:30am rush today without ever showing the slightest memory or cpu strain.  So we still have  https enabled - but not sure how our http vs https workloads differ atm.

Update 2.  rewrite as requested

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

(originally had 301 redirect - but took off pending solving memory issue)

Comment: Have you enabled http/2 on the server?

Comment: Nelson, no.  TBH I'd never heard of it.  I have to investigate more although a cursory search shows that it isn't directly supported in our Cpanel/WHM environment (which will entail custom configs to implement).  Do the symptoms I describe sound consistent with lack of httpd2?

Comment: Please post your htaccess rewrite rule

Comment: added rewrite rule as request.  It is located in DocRoot dir

Answer (score 0):

William, https will definitely increase the overhead in the way Apache serve webpages, that's why I asked if you had enabled http/2 because http/2 is way more efficient in handling https requests...It will make your website a lot faster too with less performance customization needed.

Definitely look into that.

Comment: Thanks Nelson.  I did look into a bit more.  Seems like a sensible thing to do.  I'm a little bound with Cpanel/WHM though as http/2 isn't supported in EasyApache4. Best regards